# undefined is not an object(singleValue.StopTracking) on Swipe animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a Delete on Swipe function that returns TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'singleValue.StopTracking')

Im using expo to run the project

After I swipe, expo returns the error, I click dismiss and the product disappears from my cart

I don't know what any more information to give

> const rowTranslateAnimatedValues = {};
>       Array(20)
>       .fill('')
>       .forEach((_, i) => {
>           rowTranslateAnimatedValues[`${i}`] = new Animated.Value(1);
>       });
>
> ```
> const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
>
> const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
>
> const [valueInput, setValueInput] = useState(1);
>
> const [listData, setListData] = useState(
>     Array(4)
>         .fill('')
>         .map((_, i) => ({ key: `${i}`, text: `item #${i}` }))
> );
>
> const onSwipeValueChange = swipeData => {
>   const { key, value } = swipeData;
>   if (
>       value < -Dimensions.get('window').width &&
>       !this.animationIsRunning
>   ) {
>       this.animationIsRunning = true;
>       Animated.timing(rowTranslateAnimatedValues[key], {
>           toValue: 0,
>           duration: 500,
>       })
>       .start(() => {
>           const newData = [...listData];
>           const prevIndex = listData.findIndex(item => item.key === key);
>           newData.splice(prevIndex, 1);
>           setListData(newData);
>           this.animationIsRunning = false;
>
>
>
>       });
>   }
> };
>
> const renderItem = data => (
>   <Animated.View    
>   >
>       <TouchableHighlight
>           onPress={() => console.log('You touched me')}
>           style={styles.rowFront}
>           underlayColor={'#AAA'}
>       >
>           <View>
>               <Text>I am {data.item.text} in a SwipeListView</Text>
>           </View>
>       </TouchableHighlight>
>   </Animated.View>
> );
>
> const renderHiddenItem = () => (
>   <View style={styles.rowBack}>
>       <View style={[styles.backRightBtn, styles.backRightBtnRight]}>
>           <Text style={styles.backTextWhite}>Delete</Text>
>       </View>
>   </View>
> );
>
>
> return (
>     <Block flex center style={styles.cart}>       
>
> <View style={styles.container}>
>             <SwipeListView
>                 disableRightSwipe
>                 data={cart}
>                 renderItem={renderProduct}
>                 showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
>                 keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${index}-${item.title}`}
>                 ListEmptyComponent={renderEmpty()}
>                 ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader()}
>                 ListFooterComponent={renderFooter()}
>
>                 renderHiddenItem={renderHiddenItem}
>                 rightOpenValue={-Dimensions.get('window').width}
>                 onSwipeValueChange={onSwipeValueChange}
>             />
>         </View>               
>     </Block>
>   );
> }
> ```

Comment: change `rowTranslateAnimatedValues[${ i }]` to `rowTranslateAnimatedValues[i]` and try.

Comment: @VivekDoshi same issue

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faces this problem,
you can just think `this.animationIsRunning` of a variable that manages the start and the end of animation.

So you can just use `const animationIsRunning = useRef(false)` to manage the animation state.

You can use `animationIsRunning.current` instead of `this.animationIsRunning`.
Also, `this.animationIsRunning = true` or `false` can be changed into `animationIsRunning.current = true` or `false`

See code at
https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view/pull/521/commits/2946e3a123f26ef5292a3884e0aec58436386e18